# Navbar in rails layout is not acting responsively

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I added the bootstrap.css to my stylesheet and I also added the bootstrap-responsive.css within my rails stylesheet. My problem is that the navbar shifts down to the next line, when I re-scale. However, it does not use the data-toggle function appropriately. I have no idea why. Thanks in advance.

Here's what my application.html.erb looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sigma Nu Montana</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %> // **I have a feeling the assets pipeline could be the problem?**
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
              <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
                <span class="icon-th-list"></span>

              </a>
              <a class="brand"<%= link_to "Sigma Nu Montana", welcome_index_path %></a>
              <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                  <li><%= link_to "Chapter", chapter_index_path %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Why Join Sigma Nu?", justsnuit_index_path %></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Alumni", alumni_index_path %></a></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", about_index_path %></a></li>

                </ul>


                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                  <% if user_signed_in? %> 
                  <li></li>
                  <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">

                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  <b class="caret"
                      <%= link_to current_user.full_name, edit_user_registration_path %>
                    </a></b>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><%= link_to "Meal Requests", feed_path %></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %></li>
                    </ul>
                    <% else %> 

                      <li><%= link_to "Login", login_path %></li>



                    <% end %>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
          </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
        </div>
<div class="container">

<% flash.each do |type, message| %>

<div class="alert <%= flash_class type %>">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
    <%= message %>

</div>


<% end %>

<%= yield %>


</div>

  <br>
  <br>




  </style>

  <div class="span5 offset1">

   <a href="https://twitter.com/SigmaNuGammaPhi" target="_blank"><span class="twitter-        

    hover social-slide"></span></a>

    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Sigma-Nu-Gamma-Phi-Chapter-U-of-    

    M/374382014218?ref=br_tf" target="_blank"> <span class="facebook-hover social-slide">     

    </span></a>
    <br>
    <br>


    </div>
   <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12 pagination-centered"><p>© 2013 Sigma Nu Montana.</p></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">if (window.WNElement)   

  WNElement.setMaxHeight('WNDS76Items', 415);</script>

  </div>
  </div>


  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse"` is the bug.
 So, plase try

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-th-list"></span>
```

In place of

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
            <span class="icon-th-list"></span>
```

Comment: Yea it was something similarly related, more granular. What happend was I had a css rule that had body padding top of 40px. So when I re-scaled, the responsive bootstrap kicked the navbar down. The fix was a simple css media query with a minimum width 980px that applies the body padding rule. Appreciate the response tho. :-)